# DJANGO-User switch account issue

Tags: python, django

I noticed that when I am logged in as my profile (http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/admin/ )
and I go to my template where I have the list of all users ( http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/ ) and I click on another user(mattia_mibe) to see his/her profile it switched my account, so I don't see his/her profile but I see my profile (admin) with all my descriptions but at the same time the url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/mattia_mibe/ and it recognize @mattia_mibe as users, even what it displays is my profile's descriptions(admin).

It's a bit complicated to explain, I post here some pictures in the case I did not explain the issue clearly.

[image: actual_MattiaMibe_profilePage]

[image: Logged_as_admin_after_clicking_on_mattiamibe]

core/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.homepage, name='homepage'),
    path("users/", views.UserList.as_view(), name='user_list'),
    path("user/<username>/", views.userProfileView, name='user_profile'),

]
```

core/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

# Create your views here.
from quiz.models import Questions
from jobs.models import post_job





def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'core/homepage.html')

def userProfileView(request, username):
    user= get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    jobs = post_job.objects.all()
    categories = Questions.CAT_CHOICES
    scores = []
    for category in categories:
        score = Questions.objects.filter(category=category[0], student= request.user).count()
        scores.append(score)
    context = {

    'user' : user, 'categories_scores' : zip( categories,scores),
    'jobs': jobs



    }
    return render(request, 'core/user_profile.html' , context)



class UserList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'core/users.html'
```

accounts/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from accounts.forms import FormRegistrazione

# Create your views here.

def registrazioneView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FormRegistrazione(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password1"]
            User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email)
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    else:
        form = FormRegistrazione()
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/registrazione.html', context)
```

accounts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import registrazioneView

urlpatterns = [
    path('registrazione/', registrazioneView, name='registration_view')
]
```

accounts/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class FormRegistrazione(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Terminal

```
[25/Apr/2020 13:26:24] "GET /user/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10824
[25/Apr/2020 13:26:31] "GET /users/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5301
[25/Apr/2020 13:26:37] "GET /user/mattia_mibe/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10822
[25/Apr/2020 13:26:47] "GET /accounts/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4000
[25/Apr/2020 13:26:49] "GET /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5162
[25/Apr/2020 13:26:55] "POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[25/Apr/2020 13:26:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5010
[25/Apr/2020 13:26:57] "GET /user/mattia_mibe/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6024
```

core/user_profile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block content %}
<br>
<div class="card-header">
<h3> {% if request.user == user %} Il tuo {% endif %} Profilo Utente </h3>
<br>
<h1> Ciao Studente: @{{ user }}</h1>
</div>

<br>
<br>
{% for category,score in categories_scores %}

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    {{ category.1 }} Score
  </div>

  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">CONGRATS!</h5>
    <p class="card-text"> Here your SCORE: </p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">{{ score }}</a>
    {% if score > 1 %}
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 99%" aria-valuenow="99" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="card-text">  Congratulations! Now you can apply to:</p>
    <br>
{% for job in jobs %}

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          {{job.posizione}} <strong> {{job.nome_azienda}} </strong>
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
          <ul>
    <li>    {{job.descrizione}} </li>
    <li>    {{job.email_referente}} </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="card-text">  Still not meet the requirements to apply, keep going! </p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
<br>


{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you haven't provided code snippet for your template `core/user_profile.html`. Have a look if the context variables properly address the user inside the template. It may be a case of using `{{ request.user }}` vs `{{ user }}` in the template.

The issue may be in the `core/views.py` file.

Instead of the following-

```
for category in categories:
    score = Questions.objects.filter(category=category[0], student= request.user.count()
    scores.append(score)
```

Change it to the following by removing `request.user` to `user`-

```
for category in categories:
    score = Questions.objects.filter(category=category[0], student= user.count()
    scores.append(score)
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please update the core/views.py file :)

Comment: thank you very much! it was that! Can I ask also why? what was I passing saying "request.user" instead of "user"?  thank you very much again

Comment: You're most welcome :) "request.user" picks up the user that is logged in. It's from the 'request session'. On the other hand, "user" is a clearly defined variable in your views.py which is picked up from the URL path.

What you were doing earlier was 'score' is only using the request.user (who ever is logged in) and not the user that you have define: user= get_object_or_404(User, username=username)